# Implement Undo DrawBitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawble.myImage)
canvas.drawBitmap(b, ...)
```

I'm drawing images on a canvas using the method above, and I have already added some bitmaps to my canvas(these bitmaps are static and will not be removed). Now I want to add some new bitmaps to the canvas and these bitmaps will be controllable, which means I can undo drawing these bitmaps or re-drawing them at any time.(e.g. click a button, bitmaps show, re-click the button, bitmaps disappear) Meanwhile, undo drawing or re-draw will not affect the original bitmaps on the canvas. How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing  a similar thing in my app. What I do, is to detect when the user stops touching the canvas, so I save a snapshot to a temporary file. I have an array of temp files, so it is simple to retrieve the last one when the user taps the undo button.